# listing all files in the jar of webstarted application

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

Given a webstart application composed of multiple jars, how could I list the files contained in these jars? (at runtime)

Thanks in advance,

Arnaud

**EDIT:**

The problem, with the method mentionned below (which is very similar to what I used until now), is that somehow the classpath changes when invoking webstart. Indeed, it doesn't reference your jars anymore but a `deploy.jar` instead.

As a consequence, if you run `java -cp myjars test.ListMyEntries` it will correctly print the content of your jars. On the other hand, via webstart, you will obtain the content of `deploy.jar` because this is how the classpath is defined when webstarted. I did not found any trace of the original jar names in any of the system/deployment properties.

Output sample:

```
Entries of jar file /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/deploy.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/sun/deploy/
com/sun/deploy/ClientContainer.class
com/sun/deploy/util/
com/sun/deploy/util/Trace$TraceMsgQueueChecker.class
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.. But you should sign the jar that class resides and give all permissions..

```
static void displayJarFilesEntries(){
    String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String pathSep = File.pathSeperator;  
    String[] jarOrDirectories = cp.split(pathSep);
    for(String fileName : jarOrDirectories){
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.isFile()){
            JarFile jarFile;
            try{
                jarFile = new JarFile(fileName);
            } catch(final IOException e){
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println(" Entries of jar file " + jarFile.getName());
            for(final Enumeration<JarEntry> enumJar = jarFile.entries(); enumJar
                .hasMoreElements();){
                JarEntry entry = enumJar.nextElement();
                System.out.println(entry.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: you should use `String pathSep = System.getProperty ("path.separator"); String[] jarOrDirectories = cp.split(pathSep);` since the separator might be different depending on the platform.

Comment: `File.pathSeparator` is better than `System.getProperty(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If we have disk access to these jars (which i think we would have) then jdk's [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class can be used to open up and iterate over the contents of a jar file. Each entry contained in Enumeration returned by entries method is a class name within the jar.

Comment: The main problem is that with Java Web Start, he doesn't decide where and how the jar files are stored on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Alternately, you can use JMX :

```
RuntimeMXBean bean = /* This one is provided as default in Java 6 */;
bean.getClassPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
public static List<String> listResourceFiles(ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, String endsWith) throws IOException
{
    List<String> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    URL jar = protectionDomain.getCodeSource().getLocation();
    ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());

    while(true)
    {
        ZipEntry e = zip.getNextEntry();
        if(e == null) break;
        String name = e.getName();

        if(name.endsWith(endsWith)) resources.add(name);
    }

    return resources;
}
```

```
List<String> workflowFilePaths = AppUtils.listResourceFiles(getClass().getProtectionDomain(), ".bpmn20.xml");
```